# Any alternative of secondary indexing in super column family Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, filtering, super, hector

My data model looks like this way

```
      #keyspace_name{
             #columnfamily1
               {startDate_mobileNo:  // row key
                       { Call_TYpe:  // super column
                               { xyz: value
                                 endDate : value;
                                }
                        }
                }
```

Now i want to make search result filtering the startDate_mobileNo, Call_TYpe and endDate.
This can be done by making endDate as a secondary index. But secondary indexing in a super column is not possible. So i am unable to figure how to proceed. Yes, i can do the secondary indexing filtering part by filtering result data using simple java coding. But i guess this is not the right idea as in case large data there may be scarcity of memory. So please suggest me some ideas.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can get what you want using composite keys, which have new first-class CQL support in Cassandra 1.1. See [this blog post about modeling with composites](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/schema-in-cassandra-1-1) for some more information.

Supercolumns are definitely the wrong way to go- they have always been somewhat problematic, and are now deprecated, and you can get everything you wanted from them using composites instead.

If I'm interpreting your model right, you might do something like:

```
CREATE TABLE columnfamily1 (
    startDate timestamp,
    mobileNo text,
    Call_TYpe int,
    endDate timestamp,
    xyz text,
    PRIMARY KEY (startDate, mobileNo, Call_TYpe)
);
```

You could also make a secondary index on endDate if you wanted. It's not clear to me whether you would.

If you would like to give a more concrete example of the sorts queries you need to support, I may be able to help more.

Comment: Yes Mr. Paul you have correctly interpreted my data model. And yes i also want set the endDate as secondary index. Actually i want to retrieve some results filtering those four fields from my columnfamily. But using super column family i am unable to do so with greater efficiency. One more request from my side, can i have your email id so that i can learn something from you, yes of course if you don't mind.

Comment: I'd prefer to answer questions here on SO where possible, or at least on the [Datastax support forums](http://www.datastax.com/support-forums/) so that I (and others) can help many people at once. Limited time, you know.

Comment: Mr. Paul i need another help from your side. Please visit this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10482493/astyanax-composite-column

Comment: @abhijit I would, but I don't know anything at all about Astyanax. If you can put the question in terms of pycassa or CQL or even cassandra-cli, though, I can probably help.

Comment: if i try to create a schema for mentioned data model in cassandra-cli. Then how exactly should i proceed?

Comment: @abhijit you should probably clarify your question on the other page, so that it will be visible to anyone who wants to help or who has a similar problem. It's not appropriate to ask unrelated questions here in the comments.