# Astyanax Composite Column

Tags: cassandra, composite, astyanax

I am looking for a data model look like this. In this data model i am using composite key. I know how to make a composite key. But somehow in this case i m unable to do.

```
User_Keys_By_Last_Name = {
  "Engineering" : {"anderson", 1 : "ac1263", "anderson", 2 : "724f02", ... }, 
  "Sales" : { "adams", 1 : "b32704", "alden", 1 : "1553bd", ... }, 
}
```

I want to do this in Astyanax. Please suggest me how to do it.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better you go for CQL3. 
    http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/whats-new-in-cql-3-0